# Spacing between text and iframe inside div

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm a bit 'OCD' sometimes so this is really bugging me.

http://music.george-b.co.uk is the site I am working on.

I have two divs. Both contain some text (Formatted the same apart from colour) and an iframe. The problem is the second divs text appears higher above the iframe than the other div. The code for the two divs is this:

Div 1 (Normal spacing)

```
<div class="omot">
    <h1>One Mic One Take</h1>
    <iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/287376712&amp;color=00cc11&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Div 2 (Incorrect spacing)

```
<div class="xprtd">
    <h5>XPORTED</h5>
    <iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/295617923&amp;color=ff0000&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Although one text is h1 and the other h5 they are formatted identically with css (apart form colour). I really would like the spacing to be the same. If someone could help me fix this minor but really annoying issue I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: <h5>XPORTED</h5> change those to h1's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second block of text (`h5`) has different margin values than the first one (`h1`).  The `h1` has margin before and after of 0.67em while the `h5` has margin before and after of 1.67em.  You can examine this by inspecting the elements through browser dev tools.

One solution is to manually add css rules so that the margins are the same.  Or change the `h5` to a `h1` or vice-versa.

Comment: adding 'margin-bottom: 0.67em' to the h5 css fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. Is there a better way to format text other than using all of the h1,h2... tags?

Comment: I think it depends on your preference. The built in header tags are useful if they fit your needs. There may be accessibility reasons to use them as well. Probably not much harm in just defining your own header classes and slapping them on `span` tags.

Answer (score 1):

We need to check your CSS too, the issue maybe there. Nevertheless, you should try using `margin-top:<<a negative value here>>` ex: `margin-top:-15px;`
Try that and feedback

Comment: adding 'margin-bottom: 0.67em' to the h5 css fixed the issue. Thanks!